# Unable to connect samsung galaxy S5 to mac

Tags: high-sierra, usb, android

I'm no longer able to connect a Samsung Galaxy S5 to mac High Sierra!
I used to use samsung Smart Switch app but after updating it I'm no longer able to access the phone. I tried different USB cables but same thing no connection!

Any ideas? Can I connect without the Smart Switch app?

Answer (score 1):

I had to activate the developer mode in my phone by tapping the `Build number` about 7 times. The Build number is under `Settings` -> `About Device` after that a new option will show up in settings called `Developer options`.

Under this option I activated `USB debugging` and now I can connect to my phone using the `Android Transfer File` app.